# No output from mysql query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am troubleshooting this query that I was previously trying to use to count rows but now I have discovered that 0 rows are being found in the database even though they exist. I have checked previous queries I have used and they work and look the same. The $db_conx definitely works to connect to the database as I am using it on other web pages. Does any one have any suggestions? Thanks

```
$result =("SELECT * FROM Request WHERE user2='joey' AND accepted='0'");
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $result);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if (rows < 1) {
    echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">No rows</strong>';
    exit();
} else {
    echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">Rows exist</strong>';
    exit();
}
```

Comment: And `rows` not equal `$rows`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Sorry I typed rows wrong on here and it does say rows in my code I am compiling. I have tried SELECT * still nothing

Comment: @AbraCadaver I had an answer ready for this, but I'm hesitant to click on "Post Your Answer". Edit: good thing I didn't.

Comment: actually, I decided to. another error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You edited your original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33307758/1

being `SELECT FROM Request`

You have selected "nothing" from your query

```
SELECT FROM ...
```

Read the manual on SELECT:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

and this `if (rows < 1) {` - `rows` is treated as a [**constant**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) instead of a variable.

[**Error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) would have told you that if it was setup to catch and display on your system.

`if ($rows < 1) {`

and make sure you are successfully connected to your db using the same MySQL API as your query.

Check for errors on your query

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Look into using a prepared statement also.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

---

**Nota:**

You will also need to escape your data should it be coming from user input at one point.

I.e.:

```
$var = $_POST['var'];
```

and if `$_POST['var']` is equivalent to `joey's bistro`.

MySQL will see that as `WHERE user2='joey's bistro'` if it were passed as a variable in the query `WHERE user2='$var'` resulting in a syntax error.

Escaping it will render it as `joey\'s bistro` being valid syntax.

```
$var = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx,$_POST['var']);
```

This would be beneficial for just that as well as helping to protect against an SQL injection.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Thanks Fred. I changed this code so many times today to troubleshoot it I forgot to put $rows. Thanks again

Comment: @StrayGraduate You're welcome. If it's solved, great and glad to hear it. *Cheers*

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an important step to `select` something from the database and that is what are you trying to `select`.  And, you are also missing the `$` in the `rows`.

```
$result =("SELECT something FROM Request WHERE user2='joey' AND  accepted='0'");
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $result);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($rows < 1) {
   echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">No rows</strong>';
   exit();
} else {
echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">Rows exist</strong>';
exit();
}
```

Comment: so, where's the explanation here?

Comment: @Fred-ii- you edited your answer so many times, that when I came up with the `$rows` you forgot about that part ;)

Comment: my original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33307825/1 contained the fact that the OP's `rows` was treated as a constant. The other edits were "gravy" ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh I see, maybe someone just had to copy and paste it to test it, and they might like that.  At least your answer was the right one ;).  Good luck...

Comment: haha maybe ;-) As I mentioned in comments under the OP's question; I was already writing up my answer but didn't press on the "Post Your Answer" button. Your code is correct, it's just that it would be beneficial for all future readers to the question, including the OP when an explanation is given as to why their code failed. It's a "win-win" ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: OoO, I see, I'm sorry about that, I just don't look comments or other people answer when I will write my answers, just for me to practice.  Great job.  I will edit my answer and let the user know what I changed from the original code.  Thanks,

Comment: No worries :-) I didn't rely on comments neither when I wrote mine. Some do that, I'm not like that. and you're welcome and thanks.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer :-) upvoted, *cheers*. Am sure others are thankful also.